# Create Generic Type adapter class not working

Tags: java, android, generics

I have 3 different `ArrayList`s and each one has data from a specific object : `Type_A`, `Type_B` and `Type_C` . Each one has a field `private String name` so I moved that field to a `Type_General` and made all 3 types to extend the general type.

I want to use an Adapter for each list of items and I thought if they all extend the same type (`Type_General` ) and the Adapter uses a `List<Type_General>` I won't have to create 3 different Adapters, one for every type.

But to my amusement when I tried to instantiate one for `Type_A` I got a red line error in my IDE (`Android Studio`) cause it expects a `List<Type_General>` and I pass `List<Type_A>`

Code of my Adapter class :

```
class SuggestionsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SuggestionsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Type_General> mDataset;
private EditProfileFragment.SuggestionsEditTextEnum editTextEnum;
private EditText editText;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView mTextView;
    ViewHolder(TextView v) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = v;
    }
}

SuggestionsAdapter(List<Type_General> myDataset, EditProfileFragment.SuggestionsEditTextEnum editTextEnum,
                   EditText editText, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
    this.editTextEnum = editTextEnum;
    this.editText = editText;
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
}

@Override
public SuggestionsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.textview_with_rounded_corners, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder((TextView) v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SuggestionsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.mTextView.setText(capitalizeFirstLetter(mDataset.get(position).getName()));
    holder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (editTextEnum) {
                case Type_A:
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                case Type_B:
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                case Type_C:
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

public void addItem(Type_General item) {
    mDataset.add(item);
}

public void addAllItems(List<Type_General> items) {
    mDataset.clear();
    mDataset.addAll(items);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

}
```

Shouldn't that work since `Type_General` is the parent class of `Type_A`, `Type_B` and `Type_C` ?

Comment: Collection<ChildClass> cannot be casted into Collection<ParentClass>. However you can do `Collection<ChildClass> collection = (Collection<ChildClass>) ((Object) yourParentClassCollection)` but that is pretty ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collection<ChildClass>` cannot be casted into `Collection<ParentClass>`. That might be a compiler limitation.

However, with decent use of your collection (I mean, using List::add , List::addAll, or anything else than just simple assignation of a `Collection<ChildClass>`) there should not be any kind of issue.

If you had simply :

```
private final List<Type_General> mDataset = new ArrayList<>();

    SuggestionsAdapter(List<? extends Type_General> myDataset, EditProfileFragment.SuggestionsEditTextEnum editTextEnum,
                       EditText editText, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mDataset.addAll(myDataset);
    }
```

There wouldn't be an error, would there ?

EDIT :

I forgot to say : You can ensure the cast with declaring `List<? extends Type_General>` from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I think you have to do a `Explicit Cast` your data like this:

```
 Type_General = mDataset.get(position);

 if (Type_General instanceof Type_A){

    Type_A = (TypeA) Type_General;
 }

 holder.mTextView.setText(capitalizeFirstLetter(TypeA.getName()));
```

Comment: There's no stacktrace, it is a compilation error in his IDE.

Comment: If I'll try to run it  I get : `Error:(229, 61) error: incompatible types: List<Type_A> cannot be converted to List<Type_General>`

Comment: I think i got it, instead to pass a `List<Type_A>`  to your adapter, create a `List<Type_General>` and add all the objects `Type_A` or `Type_B` inside the `List<Type_General>` and then pass it to your adapter using the constructor.